# How to pronounce "l'organisateur de l'événement"?

Tags: prononciation, oral, intonation

What is the proper pronunciation of this sentence as an event organizer?

This is the example:

> Je suis Joana l'organisateur de l'événement, quand est la date exacte de l'événement ?

Comment: You should rather say *quelle est la date de l'événement*.

Comment: You should say "*organisatrice*" instead of "*organisateur*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to pronounce "l'organisateur de l'événement"

https://www.naturalreaders.com/online?s=V2ca8wou4yalssgcksw0so0gw4g.pdf&t=NaturalReader%20Document

But if you are a girl, you could say "l'organisatrice de l’événement"

Answer (score 7):

It is pronounced as documented in the dictionaries:

[IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) /lɔʁɡanizatœʁ də levεnmɑ̃/

There might be language register or regional variations. For example the *e* in *de* might be mute ( /dlevεnmɑ̃/ ) and while the *e* located before *-ment* in *événement* is mute in standard French, it is generally pronounced in southern France; *-ment* might also be pronounced /mɛ̃ŋ/ there.

Note that (safely) assuming Joana is a feminine first name, that should be *l'organisa**trice** de l'événement*.

*Événement* is written using the traditional spelling which doesn't match its pronunciation. A new accepted spelling is *évènement*.

As Grep pointed out, there is an adverb mismatch. That should be either:

> *Quelle est la date exacte de l'événement.*

or, keeping *quand*:

> *Quand exactement aura lieu l'événement*